# Function that saves new WP Query to array for use on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, object, return

Is it possible to run a function that always queries for a related post and saves that array to a variable in Wordpress?

```
if ( !function_exists( 'the_query_vars' ) ) {
function the_query_vars() {
  global $post;

  if ($post->post_status == 'publish') {  

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sponsor'
    ,'posts_per_page' => 1
    ,'post_belongs' => $post->ID
    ,'post_status' => 'publish'
    ,'suppress_filters' => false
    );

    $sponsor_query = new WP_Query($args);
    return $the_query; 
  }
 add_action( 'init', 'the_sponsor_vars' );
} }
```

Then I just wanted to use the `$the_query` "object?" and use it as if I had done a regular `new WP_Query()` from within the template file? Calling it out with familiar hook like:

`echo $the_query->post_title`

Tried the simplest thing first:
`<?php print_r($the_query);?>`

Been unsuccessful in returning the array of variables.

I considered that it was because the variable wasn't globally set, but I thought the advantage of the `return` command was to essentially store the results for use if the function is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns the Variable and not make it global.
If you want to access the result you have to assign the result of the function to a variable.

```
if (!function_exists('the_query_vars')) {
    function the_query_vars()
    {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_status == 'publish') {

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'sponsor'
            , 'posts_per_page' => 1
            , 'post_belongs' => $post->ID
            , 'post_status' => 'publish'
            , 'suppress_filters' => false
            );

            $sponsor_query = new WP_Query($args);
            return $sponsor_query;
        }
        add_action('init', 'the_sponsor_vars');
    }
}
```

and where you want to use the result of the function:

```
$the_query = the_query_vars();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am seeing that it works when I do a:

`print_r($the_query)`

 But when I tried to get something from the array like:

echo $the_query->post_title

That doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you use it like documented!? Including the loop and so on!? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop